# Data type for an ID field (int or varchar)

Tags: types, int, varchar

What is advisable data type of an ID field (such as state ID or web_form_id or employeeID)?
Is it best to use an int data type of varchar (and why) ?

Answer (score 3):

For an Id, which is going to be unique to each user, its recommended to go with `int`, and as this sounds more like an sql question, in the `auto_increment` mode.